# Preventing a window from gaining input focus

Tags: x11

I developed a program that allows me to control the X11 communication between a client and the X11 server. I want to use it to control mouse and keyboard inputs provided to the client. Also, I want to run the client program while being able to interact with other windows.

Unfortunately, whenever I sent a "fake" mouse click or "fake" keyboard button click to the program, the window gains input focus. This is not what I want, as it steals input focus from whatever window has it at the time.

I tried already multiple approaches, such as preventing the client to ask for input focus by not forwarding `SetInputFocus` requests to the X11 server and faking `GetInputFocus` responses, etc. but my tries always resulted in the client window freezing.

Please recommend me an approach to solve this problem.

Comment: With Windows  / Win32 I'd get the current focus, then send my keys or click, then bounce focus back to the old window.  If I controlled the source for a process and wanted it to never gain focus I'd have it process the focus and app activation events itself and do something similar.  You might need to do the bounce-back after a delay if losing focus prevents handling the clicks correctly.

Comment: You mean you’ve got a proxy sitting between the X server and the client? Or is it some other way?

Comment: @user3840170 Yes, that is correct. For my client I define `DISPLAY=:2` and my proxy forwards traffic to `DISPLAY=:1`.

Comment: In the meantime, I managed to get a little further. I achieved to click in my client program and the visible content of the client program changed. However, after another mouse interaction, the client stopped. I guess this is already more than an instant freeze after the first mouse click. I had a bug in my sequence number generation for my faked server messages. I am now trying to understand the X11 communication by using both my own proxy server and xtrace. Needless to say, that this process of solving the problem is very painful.

Comment: I should say that I now reverted back to my initial approach of filtering out `SetInputFocus` messages from the client. However, it seems to me that this requires me to emulate the behavior of the server to some extent, which is what I am now trying to do. I wish there was a simpler solution though.

Comment: Your approach with SetInputFocus/GetInputFocus should work, you may want to debug your application to see where the problem is. If all else fails, run your application within XNest.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the XTEST Extension Protocol?

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/xtest.html

The `XTEST` extension of X11 is a standard way of sending "fake" input on X11 and might handle some of the edge cases better than crafting and sending raw events yourself.

One simple solution, albeit a bit hacky, would be after sending input with `XTEST`, immediately revert focus back to the original window using `XSetInputFocus()`. This might result in a very brief focus switch but if done quickly enough, it might be barely noticeable.

Another approach worth trying would be to try to "lock focus" on your window before sending any input, this way you could force the focus to remain on the currently active window using a combination of window manager functions and X11 functions. After the simulated input, you could then release this focus lock if you wished.

In this sense, that might be a better way to solve this, using something like "WM_HINTS" to prevent the target window from ever taking focus.

For example using `WM_HINTS`.

```
// Where 0xSOME_WINDOW_ID is ID of the target window 
// you want to prevent gaining focus
Window targetWindow = 0xSOME_WINDOW_ID;
XWMHints *hints = XAllocWMHints();
// hint the window manager not to give focus to this window
hints->input = False; 
hints->flags = InputHint;
XSetWMHints(display, targetWindow, hints);
XFree(hints);
```

However `WM_HINTS` are just that - hints...there is no way to know if a given WM will respect the input hint without trying it.

**Edit**

To "lock focus" - or making a window essentially modal - you would need to use a combination of window manager functions and X11 functions. One idea would be setting the `NET_WM_STATE` property to `NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE`. This should keep your desired window always on top. To bolster this you could listen for "Focus Changes" and ensure your target window remain active. Something like...

```
// listen for focus change...
XSelectInput(display, window, FocusChangeMask);

// Dispatch your events..

// while...
XEvent event;
XNextEvent(display, &event);
if (event.type == FocusOut) {
    // If focus is lost then bring it back
    XSetInputFocus(display, window, RevertToParent, CurrentTime);
}
```

Again the specifics are going to depend heavily on your WM, environment, etc. I'd suggest you have a play around with some different ideas and if you get stuck with some specific implementation to post some code with a more focused question. As is the topic is simply too large to give a definitive answer or cover the possible nuances and edge cases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! These are some interesting ideas. I tried already to alter the `WM_HINTS` using `xprop` and it didn't work. Chances are that I did it wrongly, but so I'm sceptical about this idea. Thanks for the hint to `XTEST`, that is good to know. At the same time though, my input generation works very reliably already. The idea of reverting input focus is an interesting one though. I am just concerned that when typing it interrupts constantly and every 5th keypress or so gets lost. I think it would drive me nuts.

Comment: The idea with locking the focus sounds very interesting! Could you please provide more details how to implement this? I've never heard of focus locking and a quick google search doesn't return much.

Comment: @FelixCrazzolara sure, but it is a little outside the scope of the question as it would be specific to the WM you are using, really it would be a combination of things....but please see my edit.